# Avoid landing page redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have create a simple webpage at uploaded at a free Linux-shared server where i have bought my domain name.

My cpanel at "Advanced DNS Zone Editor" is configure :

Name  //  TTL  //  Class  //  Type  //  Record

- example.com.             14400   IN  A       123.4.567.890
- localhost.example.com.   14400   IN  A       123.0.0.1
- mail.example.com.        14400   IN  CNAME   example.com
- www.example.com.         14400   IN  CNAME   example.com

I have put in all pages meta tags like this one:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/page2.html"/>
```

I have create .htaccess and upload it in server.
My code inside is this:

```
#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Why i am getting this error?
Avoid landing page redirects
To speed up page load times for visitors of your site, remove as many landing page redirections as possible, and make any required redirections cacheable if possible.

```
http://www.example.com/page2.html is a permanent redirect to http://example.com/page2.html
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That sounds like a Gmetrix message. I don't think there is much you can do about that message because you are redirecting www to non www so it has to redirect to the equivalent page. You are already using 301 so it's cacheable as well.

Comment: Thank you for your message...Yes, it is GTmetrix. So i am ok? How can i make it short-cacheable?

Comment: R=301 makes it cacheable.